# Is it possible to model unidirectional evolution of an atom-photon system using the Schrodinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, photon-emission, coherence

The physical system I'm imagining is pretty simple: suppose there's an atom in free space with three states $|g_0\rangle, |g_1\rangle, |e\rangle$ initialized to some superposition of $|g_0\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$, say $|\psi_0\rangle = (|g_0\rangle + |e\rangle) / \sqrt{2}$. The atom is coupled to a quantized electromagnetic field described by a Fock basis where, if $n$ is the number of excitations in the field, the total state $|e, n\rangle$ will spontaneously decay to $|g_1, n + 1\rangle$.

I'll state the question here, although I'd also like to outline some thoughts I have on it below: Is it possible to write down a (possibly non-Hermitian) Hamiltonian I could plug into the Schrodinger equation that would move an initial state $|\psi_0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$ to $(|g_0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle + |g_1\rangle \otimes |1\rangle) / \sqrt{2}$, such that (a) there is no chance of reproducing the initial state and (b) the total state remains pure?

---

If I were to only look at the atom, I would see that its state gradually becomes mixed because spontaneous emission is a dissipative process that occurs non-deterministically and so forth. This process is well-modeled by the Lindblad master equation, which describes the time evolution of the appropriate density matrix and introduces terms outside the usual Hamiltonian that describes the system.

But, if I include the emitted photon (that is, the state of the field) in the model, working in a Hilbert space with states that look like $|a, n\rangle$ where $a$ is the state of the atom and $n$ is the number of excitations in the field, it seems like I should be able to model the emission process without decreasing the purity of the total state (i.e. at long times after $|e, 0\rangle$ has decayed to $|g_1, 1\rangle$, the phase of this subspace relative to $|g_0, 0\rangle$ should remain well-defined), since the system would then be closed. The Jaynes-Cummings model describes an atom coupled to an optical cavity and works explicitly in the basis I've described, but allows the system to return to the initial state because in such a scenario the atom can reabsorb photons previously emitted into the cavity. In contrast, Wigner-Weisskopf theory (as I understand it) would produce the desired transition irreversibly, but doesn't fit everything into a single Hamiltonian matrix I could plug 'n' chug with in a numerical integrator.

It's worth noting that there are many experimental results demonstrating that the total post-emission state should have some significant degree of purity. As a minimal example, you can treat the resulting atom-photon state as a Bell state, feed it into a an appropriate analyzer, and observe parity oscillations as in e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.17455).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the Hamiltonian $$H = i g \left( \hat{a} \left| e \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle g_1 \right| - \hat{a}^\dagger \left| g_1 \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle e \right| \right)$$ for the photon-atom interaction. I guess the photon mode has the standard Hamiltonian $$H = \hbar \omega \left( \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} - 1/2 \right),$$ and we can ignore the other frequencies that don't couple to the atom.

If you construct the corresponding unitary evolution operator, you should be able to use [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff / Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula) to separate the two noncommuting terms into a product of two unitaries, one involving $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$, and the other involving $\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}$. See Appendix C of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275). You don't need a Lindbladian, but you could recover one for the atom or the light by tracing over the Hilbert space of the other.

You could also use the Jaynes-Cumming model you mention, where $$H = \Omega \sigma^z + \omega a^\dagger a + g \left( \hat{a} \, \sigma^+ + \hat{a}^\dagger \sigma^- \right),$$ where $\sigma^z = \left| g_1 \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle g_1 \right| - \left| e \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle e \right|$ and $\sigma^+ = \left| g_1 \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle e \right|$ and $\sigma^- = \left| e \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle g_1 \right|$. In the limit $\left| \Omega - \omega \right| \gg g$, we can use perturbation theory to recover the effective Hamiltonian $$H = \Omega \sigma^z + \omega \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} + \frac{g^2}{\omega - \Omega} \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} \, \sigma^z \, .$$

The Wigner-Weisskopf mechanism that I would use to describe fluorescence, e.g., is very complicated and you'd want to make various approximations and do a page worth's of calculations (or more) to work out a soluble unitary operator. I suggest using one of the above, but there are papers on the latter in the quantum optics literature.

Applying a unitary operator to a pure state will give you another pure state. you can only get a mixed state upon tracing out one of the two degrees of freedom (EM mode or atom).

Let me know if you have lingering questions or anything I wrote above was unclear.